# Download the file as a zip in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am designing an educational site. When the user downloads a training course, I want this download (training course) to be done in the form of compression (zipper), please give a solution

My code:

```
  public Tuple<byte[],string,string> DownloadFile(long episodeId)
    {
        var episode=_context.CourseEpisodes.Find(episodeId);
        string filepath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
      "wwwroot/courseFiles",
            episode.FileName);
        string fileName = episode.FileName;
        if(episode.IsFree)
        {
            byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
           return Tuple.Create(file, "application/force-download",fileName);                   
        }
        if(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
           
     if(IsuserIncorse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, 
          episode.CourseId))
            {
                byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
          return Tuple.Create(file, "application/force-download", fileName);             
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You can't be using both ASP.NET Core and the ancient ASP.NET MVC 4. What are you actually using?

Comment: No, I only use  ASP.NET Core & template RazorPage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write a demo to show how to download `zip` file from .net core:

**First** , Add NuGet package `SharpZipLib` , create an  `Image`  Folder in `wwwroot` and put some picture in it.

[image]

**controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment _IHosting;

        public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment IHosting)
        {
            _IHosting = IHosting;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public FileResult DownLoadZip()
        {
            var webRoot = _IHosting.WebRootPath;
            var fileName = "MyZip.zip";
            var tempOutput = webRoot + "/Images/" + fileName;

            using (ZipOutputStream IzipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(System.IO.File.Create(tempOutput)))
            {
                IzipOutputStream.SetLevel(9);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                var imageList = new List<string>();

                imageList.Add(webRoot + "/Images/1202.png");
                imageList.Add(webRoot + "/Images/1data.png");
                imageList.Add(webRoot + "/Images/aaa.png");

                for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++)
                {
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(imageList[i]));
                    entry.DateTime= DateTime.Now;
                    entry.IsUnicodeText = true;
                    IzipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

                    using (FileStream oFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(imageList[i]))
                    {
                        int sourceBytes;
                        do
                        { 
                            sourceBytes = oFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            IzipOutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
                        }while (sourceBytes > 0);
                    }
                }
                IzipOutputStream.Finish();
                IzipOutputStream.Flush();
                IzipOutputStream.Close();
            }

            byte[] finalResult = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempOutput);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(tempOutput)) { 
                System.IO.File.Delete(tempOutput);
            }
            if (finalResult == null || !finalResult.Any()) {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Nothing found"));

            }

            return File(finalResult, "application/zip", fileName);
        }
    }
```

when I click the `downloadZip` ,it will download a `.zip` file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simple example that follows illustrates the use of the `static ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` method which, despite the fact that it is in the `System.IO.Compression` namespace , actually resides in the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` assembly, so you need to add a reference to that in your controller.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public FileResult Download()
{
    List<string> files = new List<string> { "filepath1", "filepath2" };
    var archive = Server.MapPath("~/archive.zip");
    var temp = Server.MapPath("~/temp");

    // clear any existing archive
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(archive))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(archive);
    }
    // empty the temp folder
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(temp).ToList().ForEach(f => System.IO.File.Delete(f));

    // copy the selected files to the temp folder
    files.ForEach(f => System.IO.File.Copy(f, Path.Combine(temp, Path.GetFileName(f))));

    // create a new archive
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(temp, archive);

    return File(archive, "application/zip", "archive.zip");
}
```

Answer from Source - [MikesDotNetting](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/306/working-with-zip-files-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried multiple ways to do it
But some work if a folder path is specified, others only work with images and text files,
As for executable files such as: ( `.dll` or `.exe` ...etc) after decompression, they do not work well
After multiple trials, I came up with the following code.

> **If you want to compress only one file or specific files (not a folder)**

You can try the following code

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string fileFullName)
{
    string filePath = fileFullName; // Replace the path to your file
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    string compressedFilePath = filePath + ".zip";

    try
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(compressedFilePath)) System.IO.File.Delete(compressedFilePath);
        
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(compressedFilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath, fileName);
            }
        }

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(compressedFilePath))
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(compressedFilePath);
            System.IO.File.Delete(compressedFilePath);
            return File(fileBytes, "application/x-zip-compressed", fileName + ".zip");
        }
        return NotFound("The file: " + compressedFilePath + " is  not exists!");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return BadRequest("Some error on the file: " + compressedFilePath + " !");
    }
}
```